# How configure 2 git repo for one folder?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository cloned from a private git server as following on my machine:

/private-repo
 /.git
 /file-1
 /dir-1
  file-2
 /file-3

I would like to be able to put this repository on GitHub as a new project in such a way that modifying for example file-3 will results in modifications to be committed and pushed in both repositories. I need to do that because I want then to clone the repo from a machine where only GitHub is accessible and not the private server. So my question is, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use a git submodule which means you can configure your two repositories to point to a shared submodule. The file in question can then be in the submodule instead.

Comment: Will the submodule solution work if if then I want to clone the repo from a machine having acess only to GitHub and not the private server ? I forgot to mention that this is a constraint for me, and I just checked that git submodules will require the cloner to fetch from both reposiotries